# Sending data from Python to Javascript using only one URL in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am currently working in a Python application that has to send some data (latitude, longitude) to a Javascript file in order to show the current position of a device in a map. I am sending the data as JSON and I am using Flask to send it, but I faced a problem and I have not found a solution yet.

I know how to send data using Flask:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/myRoute')
def sendData():
    myDict = {'latitude':46.6205, 'longitude':-15.3826}
    myDictJson = json.dumps(myDict)

    return myDictJson

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host:'localhost', port=9999)
```

But the thing is that the latitude and the longitude are not fixed, they will change every X seconds and I also need the URL to be fixed. How can I implement it? Should I use something different from Flask?

Comment: You should probably poll from the Client Side or use Websockets for this, sending Data from the server is never really applicable unless it's a response to a request from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

`@app.route(/myRoute)` should be: `@app.route('/myRoute', methods=["GET"])`, by adding `methods=["GET"]` you can browse the link and see the *return* in your browser.
The *URL* will be fixed since you specify it in *Flask*. Since latitude and longitude change all the time this information should be stored somewhere, just use it in your *myDict* and request the data over and over again in your *javascript*.

Comment: It is true, I forgot to add the apostrophe in my question, but anyway that is not the problem. Regarding to add the method, it doesn´t matter since the default method is GET.

Comment: I still do not understand how can I send changing data. Could you give an example?